# Detect a click on a div that's inside an Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to detect a click on a div by its class name that comes from a Ajax call using the .click handler. It works, but it seems when ajax fetches records a few times, my click handler breaks and keeps duplicated itself. Thus my function gets triggered multiple times when clicked once.

JQUERY

```
 $.ajax({ ...
  success: function(data){

    //add to favorite function - THIS CLICK HANDLER KEEPS DUPLICATING 
    $('.favit').click(function(){
      var cid=$(this).data("id");
      addfav(cid); //execute function
      return false;
    });

  },...
```

And if I try and pull this function out of the ajax call the click isn't detected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `.on()` and delegate the events.

```
 $.ajax({ ...
   success: function(data){

    //add to favorite function - THIS CLICK HANDLER KEEPS DUPLICATING 

  },

$(document).on("click", '.favit', function(){
  var cid=$(this).data("id");
  addfav(cid); //execute function
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Make sure here the `document` is replaced with a closest static parent, that is not affected by the AJAX calls.

Comment: OMG! I've been trying to figure this out for a several days. thank you. I'm now using .on on other functions.

Comment: @user4175297 I understand. The document is pretty clear here: [**Understanding Event Delegation**](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). Do have a look at it. `:)`

Comment: Praveen, what would make document affected by the AJAX call?

Comment: @user4175297 `document` is definitely not affected by AJAX calls.